# How to get all associated token accounts under the public key

Tags: associated-token-account

Is there a way to get all associated token account under a public key? Is there a Solana sdk do that for ys?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all `token accounts` by using https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenAccountsByOwner

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for same thing, I am creating a website dapp in which user connect his wallet and see his tokens and NFTs present in it, but I am also not finding a way to do it in js in browser.